# Why cannot I set bootstrap navbar element by CSS?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The html is:

```
      <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
       <div class="navbar-inner">
          <div class="container">
            <a class="brand" href="index.html">my brand</a>
            <ul class="nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="try.html" id="emphasize">Emphasize it</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Say, I want to add a background color. Here's what I've typed in CSS file:

```
    #emphasize{
        background: #99f;
    }
```

But there's no effect on the navigation bar. But if I try to style it by HTML style tag or Javascript, it's weirdly okay:

```
    <li><a href="tryit.html" id="emphasize" style="background: #99f">Emphasize it</a></li>
```

or

```
    document.getElementById('emphasize').style.background = '#99f';
```

Comment: Is any of the CSS in the CSS file working? If not it's not been included in your HTML file/been uploaded

Comment: Where is your css code? in external file?

Comment: @user125697 Other style definition in my own style file is working correctly. When it comes to navigation bar, it fails to work.

Comment: @NaveTseva Yeah. It is an external file linked in the head of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I think the background color is being overridden by preceding color. So you may try using this CSS instead.

```
#emphasize{
    background: #99f !important;
}
```

which will force rendered to use this color instead..

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Also I inspected the item a#emphasize but find no background property in the computed style of browsers (Firefox, Chrome, and Opera). The Javascript way actually adds a style tag to the #emphasize node, which is like how HTML style tag behaves, and thus could work.